# Ternary operator in C?

Tags: c

Why is the output displayed as 3?  What is the concept behind this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 5, b = 4, c;
    c = a > b ? 1, 2, 3 : 2, 5, 6;
    printf("%d\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: and why would you write like a code like that? can you spell the logic in simple English? if no, then dont write the code like that.

Comment: You are putting yourself at risk of downvotes by people who fight for the recognition of C and C++ as separate languages. (I did not downvote.)

Comment: Although this is only another writing for the `if`query.

Comment: Are you aware of how the two operators `?:` and `,`work and their precedence?

Comment: @Yunnosch  basically, when `a` is greater than `b` `3`will be assigned to `c` else `6`. But why are those other integers ignored?

Comment: @Alan I know both. I try to gauge OPs level of knowledge, they seem to be unaware of how e.g. the `,` operator works.

Comment: Close-voters for the reason of lack of MCVE, please elaborate.

Comment: This question gives the strong impression of being a homework assignment. Most users here do not take kindly to being asked to do other peoples (home)work. Please state whether this is homework and whether you would appreciate help according to the compromise described here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @Yunnosch I know that you know how this logic works, that's why I am asking you, why `3`or`6`get assigned and the other integer get skipped.

Comment: @Alan Yes I know. But this is probably a homework question. In that case I insist on doing it the didactic way described in the link I provided. Please be patient. If it is not homework, then it is a question deserving downvotes for lack of own research effort. Also, I already practically gave the answer in my comments. Somewhat well hidden of course.

Comment: @Alan: Do you want to check what happens if you invert the condition?  When does `6` get assigned to `c`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler when `a<b` althought I am not the `OP`I am just curious why the other `int's`get skipped...

Comment: @Yunnosch I think I got it from your hidden comment ;)

Comment: @Alan Not yet. Mind the trap hinted at by Jonathan Leffler.

Comment: @Alan: "precedence rules". Note that `,` has lower precedence than assignment; if the condition is inverted, the value assigned to `c` is `2`, not `6` — the values `5` and `6` are ignored.  So are the first `1` and `2`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the headsup, I missed that trap.

Comment: OP seems to have abandoned the question. I will check later.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks, got it! Keep helping!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler only to ask If I understood right, the `:` operator has a higher precedence than the `,` that means if, in this case, the `then`assignment gets executed, the `3`will be assigned (as it is at the left of the `:` operator (from left to right) and with the inverted condition, the `2`is the nearest value on the right. Or?

Comment: @Alan To check whether you really got it, answer yourself the question "Where does the 6 go?" It is ignored, but in an intricate way and can be made "visible".

Comment: @Alan: As I said, it's a bit intricate.  The `:` is only part of the operator, but it does have a grouping role for the comma expressions between the `?` and the `:`.

Comment: Didn't get it @JonathanLeffler because in the ternary conditional (`?:`)the precendece is from `right to left` , so it is logical that `3`will be assigned as it is on the right side of the three integers but why doesn't `6`get assigned then as it is on the right hand side of the other `3 int's`. I searched for it but It seems I don't get it...

Comment: @Alan: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51607352/15168) — I hope that explains what goes on sufficiently.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, I think so. Because the compiler sees the `((1,2,3) :2),5,6` in brackets as you mentioned. That is why the precedence is from left to right the last integer gets assigned (`3`or `2`). (Because althought `?:`precedence is from right to left the paranthese have a higher precendence).

Answer (score 7):

The line of code containing the ternary operator is intricate and intriguing.  It also has subtle but crucial asymmetries in the way it is interpreted that are far from obvious when it is written as shown in the question.  Let's consider a minor variant of the original code as follows, which exercises both the 'true' and 'false' parts of the ternary operator (in two separate statements — though I could have made a function and passed arguments to that instead):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 5, b = 4, c;
    c = a > b ? 1, 2, 3 : 2, 5, 6;
    printf("a = %d, b = %d, c = %d\n", a, b, c);
    a = b - 1;
    c = a > b ? 1, 2, 3 : 2, 5, 6;
    printf("a = %d, b = %d, c = %d\n", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

The output from this program is:

```
a = 5, b = 4, c = 3
a = 3, b = 4, c = 2
```

What's going on here?

Remember, the comma operator has even lower precedence than the assignment operator, so that you can, if you wish, write code such as:

```
if (a > b)
    c = 2, d = 3, e = 6;
```

and there are three assignments in the body of the `if` statement.  That would not be regarded as good code for general use, but the technique can be useful in a macro — very occasionally it can be useful in a macro.

Let's add some parentheses — the correct set of parentheses as the compiler interprets the code:

```
 c =  a > b  ?  1, 2, 3  : 2 , 5, 6;
(c = (a > b) ? (1, 2, 3) : 2), 5, 6;
```

The condition `a > b` controls whether `1, 2, 3` or `2` is evaluated, and the result is assigned to `c`.  The result of `1, 2, 3` is `3`, so if `a > b`, the value assigned is `3` (as in the question), and if `a <= b`, the value assigned is `2`.  The `5` and the `6` are evaluated for side-effects — but there are no side-effects so they are effectively discarded.

The `:` of the ternary operator has a grouping effect on the code between the `?` and the `:` which does not occur after the `:`.

Note that to get this code to compile, I had to discard my default compiler options.  With the code in the question and my normal, default compiler options, I get (source code in `top67.c`):

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
>     top67.c -o top67 
top67.c:3:5: error: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Werror=strict-prototypes]
 int main()
     ^~~~
top67.c: In function ‘main’:
top67.c:6:18: error: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
     c = a > b ? 1, 2, 3 : 2, 5, 6;
                  ^
top67.c:6:21: error: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
     c = a > b ? 1, 2, 3 : 2, 5, 6;
                     ^
top67.c:6:28: error: right-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
     c = a > b ? 1, 2, 3 : 2, 5, 6;
                            ^
top67.c:6:31: error: right-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
     c = a > b ? 1, 2, 3 : 2, 5, 6;
                               ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
$
```

I'd get more errors from the code shown in this answer.  You should be compiling with similar options to avoid problems in your own code.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
c = a > b ? 1, 2, 3 : 2, 5, 6;
```

is understood by the compiler as:

```
(c = a > b ? (1, 2, 3) : 2),
5,
6;
```

> In the C and C++ programming languages, the comma operator
>   (represented by the token ,) is a binary operator that evaluates its
>   first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second
>   operand and returns this value (and type).
>   If there are more than two operands, the last expression will be returned.

At this condition `(c = a > b ? (1, 2, 3) : 2)`

`a > b` will return true

so it will evaluate first operand `1` and discards the result then evaluate the second operand `2` and discard the result then evaluate the third operand `3` and return its value which is `3`

and then `5, 6;` will be discarded after evaluating them because they don't produce any side effects.

at the end the output of program will be `3`.

but if we consider `a < b` at condition `(c = a < b ? (1, 2, 3) : 2)`

in this case it will evaluate else condition and return its value which is `2`

also `5, 6;` will be discarded after evaluating them because they don't produce any side effects.

at the end the output of program will be `2`.

Answer (score 0):

if (a>b)

value of c = expect integer expression before `:` token

else

value of c = expect integer expression after `:` token

if c is integer type and we are using ternary operator ? then compiler expects integer data type before and after `:` token

if we are using unsigned integer data type, it will convert it to signed integer data type

Comment: You may what to use code blocks or inline code format (back ticks ` ` around your code) to make the answer easier to read